# Can a traded player play for two teams in one week?

Tags: american-football

Suppose a player in a Thursday Night Football game catches the eye of a team playing on the Sunday or Monday of the same Week, and a trade is quickly completed in the interim.  The player is able to show up at his new team's game, would he be allowed to dress/play for that game?  Is such a quick trade even permissible under league rules?

Comment: I cannot find any actual statement in the rulebook or the game operations manual, but this would not be allowed by the player's union in any case.

Comment: @Adam Do you have anything to back that up?  Player's union is not in charge.  What is in the collective bargaining agreement rules.

Comment: As I do not have the actual rules or legal documents in front of me, researching this question has given me the following: If a player played a Thursday night game (assume before the bye week), a player is paid per game each week plus for the bye week. Therefore `paycheck per week = salary/17`. If a player was traded and played the Thursday and the Sunday, this would essentially act as an "18th game", which he wouldn't be compensated for in the big picture. And that is where the player's union would come into play. Let me research more and get back to you @paparazzo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The commissioner's office is responsible for making sure teams are following protocol on trades. You can only play in one game per week.

Example - Percy Harvin playing for the Seahawks in a Thursday night game was not allowed to play for Jets that weekend.

Example - Will Allen [played in 17 games in one year](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/A/AlleWi21/fantasy/2013/) (2013; when the season was only 16 games) - he was traded to a team that already had their bye week when his team had not. I am not sure if he got paid more for it.